# Is $\det(X^T A X)/\det(X^T B X) = \det(A)/\det(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let's assume $A,B$ are symmetric, positive definite real $n \times n$ matrices. Does it hold that
$$\frac{\det(X^T A X)}{\det(X^T B X)} = \frac{\det(A)}{\det(B)}$$ for all $X$ real $n \times p$ matrices for which the denominator on the left is nonzero?

Comment: For $n=p$, the proof is trivial due to $det(X^TAX)=det(X^T)det(A)det(X)$.

Comment: Not true. Take $A=I_{2\times 2}$, $B=2I_{2\times 2}$, and $X=(1,2)^T$

Comment: @MatthewPilling, good observation, that seems to be a complete answer, why not post it as an answer so this question can be closed?

Comment: I prefer to build my reputation by solving more interesting and difficult problems, but I'll post it as an answer if you find my response especially useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Take $A=I_{2\times 2}, B=2I_{2\times 2}$ and $X=(1,2)^T$.